# How to set a conditional panel to a selectinput in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to add a second  inputpanel in my shiny application which content depend on the input of the first inputpanel choice, I tried tout use condional panel with no luck.

---

```
#ui.R

TO <- read.csv("~/TO/TO/TO.csv", sep=";")
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("dasboard"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins

sidebarLayout(

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("country", label = h4("Pays"), 
                choices = levels(as.factor(TO$Pays))),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.country == 'Allemagne'",        
    selectInput("to", label = h4("Tour opérateur"), 
              choices = levels(as.factor(as.character(TO[as.character(TO$Pays)=="Allemagne",]$TO))))),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.country == 'Angleterre'",        
    selectInput("to", label = h4("Tour Operator"), 
                choices = levels(as.factor(as.character(TO[as.character(TO$Pays)=="Angleterre",]$TO)))))
```

...

---

The solution that I found is to create a conditionalPanel for every value of the first inputPanel But is the second inputPanel output is only correct for the first value.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please show what you have got so far...

Comment: As you can see above the code I am still looking for a solution

Answer (score 4):

I know the approach below is not via the conditional panels, as I think it would be simpler to do it via examples given below.

First you can use `updateSelectInput` to update your entries, something like this

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    selectInput('data', 'Data', c('mtcars', 'iris')),
    selectInput('Cols', 'Columns', "")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    outVar <- reactive({
      mydata <- get(input$data)
      names(mydata)
    })
    observe({
      updateSelectInput(session, "Cols",choices = outVar()
      )})
  }
))
```

Other way you can use `renderUI` to create the `selectInput` and populate it like so:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    selectInput('data', 'Data', c('mtcars', 'iris')),
    uiOutput('columns')
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$columns <- renderUI({
      mydata <- get(input$data)
      selectInput('columns2', 'Columns', names(mydata))
    })
  }
))
```

**Edit: how to add multiple widgets inside the `renderUI`**
You need to wrap your `divs` inside the `tagList()` like so:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    selectInput('data', 'Data', c('mtcars', 'iris')),
    uiOutput('columns')
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$columns <- renderUI({
      mydata <- get(input$data)
      tagList(
      selectInput('columns2', 'Columns', names(mydata)),
      selectInput('columns3', 'Columns 2', names(mydata)))
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Hi, regarding the second post above, if I want to put multiple selectInputs and slider upon selecting iris and mtcars, can you please help.